# The NP array has the shape (2186, 128). I am interested in applying the obtained array to SVM

Tags: python, arrays, numpy, machine-learning, svm

I have extracted the output of penultimate layer (# layer 12) of CNN. The extracted NP array has the shape (2186, 128). I am interested in applying the obtained array to SVM.

Code to extract feature:

```
import numpy as np
X_train=np.array(get_activations(model=model,layer=12, X_batch=x_train)[0], dtype=np.float32)
print(X_train)
```

This gave me output of shape (2186, 128)

Code to apply above np array to SVM:

```
from sklearn.svm import SVC
clf = SVC()
clf.fit(X_train, y)
SVC(C=1.0, cache_size=200, class_weight=None, coef0=0.0,
    decision_function_shape='ovr', degree=3, gamma='auto', kernel='rbf',
    max_iter=-1, probability=False, random_state=None, shrinking=True,
    tol=0.001, verbose=False)
```

This is giving error:

```
ValueError                                Traceback (most recent call last)
<ipython-input-54-2d6b8b03f3c1> in <module>()
----> 1 clf.fit(X_train, y)
      2 SVC(C=1.0, cache_size=200, class_weight=None, coef0=0.0,
      3     decision_function_shape='ovr', degree=3, gamma='auto', kernel='rbf',
      4     max_iter=-1, probability=False, random_state=None, shrinking=True,
      5     tol=0.001, verbose=False)

~/anaconda3/lib/python3.6/site-packages/sklearn/svm/base.py in fit(self, X, y, sample_weight)
    147         self._sparse = sparse and not callable(self.kernel)
    148 
--> 149         X, y = check_X_y(X, y, dtype=np.float64, order='C', accept_sparse='csr')
    150         y = self._validate_targets(y)
    151 

~/anaconda3/lib/python3.6/site-packages/sklearn/utils/validation.py in check_X_y(X, y, accept_sparse, dtype, order, copy, force_all_finite, ensure_2d, allow_nd, multi_output, ensure_min_samples, ensure_min_features, y_numeric, warn_on_dtype, estimator)
    576                         dtype=None)
    577     else:
--> 578         y = column_or_1d(y, warn=True)
    579         _assert_all_finite(y)
    580     if y_numeric and y.dtype.kind == 'O':

~/anaconda3/lib/python3.6/site-packages/sklearn/utils/validation.py in column_or_1d(y, warn)
    612         return np.ravel(y)
    613 
--> 614     raise ValueError("bad input shape {0}".format(shape))
    615 
    616 

ValueError: bad input shape (2186, 3)
```

Answer (score 0):

It seems like your `y` has one-hot-encoding (3 classes). Transform it to integer labels (0, 1, 2) and you are good to go.

Comment: Thanks for the answer. Indeed 'y' has one-hot-encoding ((X,Y and Z) which I have manually encoded (0,0,0; 0,1,0; and so on)). I tried using integer labels (I hope I did it right) as you suggested but again I am facing the same issue.

Comment: Make sure your y looks like y = np.array([0, 0, 2, 1, 0, 2, 2, 1]). So that is has a shape=(n_samples,) or (n_samples, 1)

Comment: So did it help!?

Comment: I changed y, now in my program y_tr is array([0, 0, 0, ..., 0, 0, 0]), with the shape (2186,). Now SVC is not giving the previous error but in the output SVC parameters are getting repeted as:  SVC(C=1.0, cache_size=200, class_weight=None, coef0=0.0,
  decision_function_shape='ovr', degree=3, gamma='auto', kernel='rbf',
  max_iter=-1, probability=False, random_state=None, shrinking=True,
  tol=0.001, verbose=False)

Comment: It is not clear what you mean. To understand what a SCV does for a multiclass problem see the official documentation here: http://scikit-learn.org/stable/modules/generated/sklearn.svm.SVC.html. If you feel like there is still something wrong probably ask a new question because the current question was solved by changing the y:)